# Change text using perl or python

Tags: python, perl

There is no "sed" on my server so I should use python or perl to change recursive in all files old_text to new_text. Help me please to do it using perl or python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/old_text/new_text/g' file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: perl -p -i.bak -e 's/etc/etcetera/g' files, to leave a copy of the file with .bak as an additional suffix